# Auto crop to the maximum area that has pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Case: I have a circle 200x200, then I add a drop shadow to it, so the shadow is outside of the visible part. If I click crop and click in one of the areas to adjust it shows me the area that have pixels on it. So my question is: Is there a command to crop to that area? Because going manually isn't a good option. I am using Photoshop 21.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you told whate software you are using

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Added. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Image > Reveal All* to expand the canvas to include all pixels.

Note that if the shadow isn't perfectly symmetrical, the circle won't end up in the middle of the canvas, which might be a problem depending on your workflow.

Comment: you nailed that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to increase the Canvas size. This is the opposite of cropping.

If so, you could use *Image > Canvas size*, and increase it until it's big enough to fit the drop shadow. This will also allow you to keep the circle in the middle.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: Yes the action is increase the canvas but how do I know how much do I have to increase? I already accepted the final answer. Thanks for our time.